# Is it possible call a `Func` as if generic in c#

Tags: c#

Something like

```
void RegisterAs(Func??? register)
{
    register<IService1, Service1>(); // <-- call func like this
    register<IService2, Service2>(); // <-- or this
    register<IService3, Service3>();
}
```

And I want to call this method like

`RegisterAs(services.AddScoped)`

or

`RegisterAs(services.AddSingleton)`

Comment: Make `RegisterAs` generic?

Comment: Yes. In fact, all LINQ operators accept generic Funcs

Comment: Probably Related: [`IServiceCollection` extensions](https://dev.to/moesmp/what-every-asp-net-core-web-api-project-needs-part-6-iservicecollection-extension-19g9)

Comment: do those three interfaces share some common base-interface? If so you can use a generic constraint `void RegisterAs<T>(Func<T> f) where T: BaseInterface`.

Comment: Why have a `Func<TValue, TResult>`, when you don't use the return-value? You may chose `Action<T>` instead.

Comment: @HimBromBeere because AddScoped or AddSingleton methods are func that's why

Comment: There is no need for `Func<>` for what you want to do. Check out my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such type in C# that would allow you to invoke a delegate with generic type arguments, so this is not possible in general. If C# had higher-kinded types, this would be possible, but I don't think that is going to happen soon :(

Rather than two generic type parameters, you could allow the caller to pass in a `Func<Type, Type, IServiceCollection>`:

```
void RegisterAs(Func<Type, Type, IServiceCollection> register)
{
    register(typeof(IService1), typeof(Service1));
    register(typeof(IService2), typeof(Service2));
    register(typeof(IService3), typeof(Service3));
}
```

On the callsite, you can still do:

```
RegisterAs(services.AddScoped);
```

As this is using [the other overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addscoped(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-type-system-type)) of `AddScoped` that takes 2 `Type`s. rather than 2 generic type parameters.

Comment: We need a `Func<Type,Type,IServiceCollection>` see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VSjkQU) ;o)

Comment: Good solution (thumbs up). I did the same when I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is possible to pass a `Func<>` with Type parameters. These parameters cannot be used as generics. You can use `typeof()` and pass that as parameter.

But if you only want to have a variable lifetime you can do it in two different ways, there is **no need** to pass a Func<> in that case. Just pass the lifetime as a parameter (first two examples):

```cs
var sc = new ServiceCollection();

// With generics types
void AddMe<T, T2>(ServiceLifetime lifetime)
{
    sc.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Describe(typeof(T), typeof(T2), lifetime));
}

// Or like you have
void RegisterAs(ServiceLifetime lifetime)
{
   sc.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Describe(typeof(IService1), typeof(Service1), lifetime));
   sc.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Describe(typeof(IService2), typeof(Service2), lifetime));
   sc.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Describe(typeof(IService3), typeof(Service3), lifetime));
}

// Via a passed Func - not my preferred solution
void RegisterAsWithFunc(Func<Type, Type, IServiceCollection> register)
{
    register(typeof(IService1), typeof(Service1));
}
```

The call will be as simple as

```cs
RegisterAs(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

In contrast with the passed Func you won't see much difference at first glance:

```cs
RegisterAsWithFunc(sc.AddScoped);
```

Comment: Well, I would prefer this solution for the real problem, but it does not answers this question ... which is about generic func

Comment: I know, but sometimes thinking of a problem needs to taken outside the box :-)

Comment: But this is a question/answer site ... to get answers to the question. And the real answer is: "No, that is not possible in C#". You may add a different solution as yours, but you should answer the asked question in this answer section

Comment: I agree with you that my answer could have been a bit better and I've improved it. According to the FAQ it's also allowed to present a viable alternative which I believe this is. This platform is also about learning :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't realize that `ServiceDescriptor` class existence before. But I was also wondering how to call Func or Actions as if generic.

Comment: Sure it doesn't answer this question. But it's obvious from the context that this is really an XY problem that has other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For example, all LINQ operators accept generic Funcs. The signature of [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) is :

```
Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Boolean>)
```

The registration methods of .NET Core's Dependency Injection middleware accept generic funcs for factory methods as well, for example one of the [AddScoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addscoped-2(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-func((system-iserviceprovider-1)))) overloads is :

```
AddScoped<TService,TImplementation> (
    this Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection services, 
    Func<IServiceProvider,TImplementation> implementationFactory)
```

You can use this to create a new service instance with a custom factory method